# Fire and forget AWS step function from lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to trigger step function async through the lambda (python boto3).

Can we achieve this?

Looking at the below code, it looks like its not async.

```
client = boto3.client(STEP_FUNCTIONS)
client.start_execution(
    stateMachineArn=DATAPROCESS_STATE_MACHINE,
    name=STATEMACHINE_EXECUTION_NAME,
    input=json.dumps(state_machine_input)
)
```

Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggering the step functions execution (as you did) is async - calling `start_execution` will not wait until the state machine finish, but returns immediately.

The response specifies only if the state machine execution was triggered successfuly.

Comment: What is the way to wait for succesful execution?

Comment: When the successful execution ends notify the relevant resource - by using SNS / invoking a lambda, etc.